# Add Mean Line in front of bars in a barchart in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a bar chart in ggplot that shows everyone's age in the organisation, I have added a mean line but this line is visible at the top of the chart until it intersects with the bar chart then disappears. [image: Graph showing problem]

The code is as follows

```
`SIP %>%`
`ggplot(aes(Age))+`
`geom_vline(xintercept = mean(SIP$Age2, na.rm = TRUE), color = 'red', lty = 'dashed', lwd = 1.5)+`
`geom_bar()+`
`theme_bw()+`
` labs(title= "Age Profile November 2023",
   x = "Age",
   y = "Employee Count")`
```

Where SIP is the data source and contains all the ages. I was expecting the mean line to be visible as it continues through the bar chart

Comment: Switch `geom_vline` and `geom_bar`, i.e. `geom_bar(...) + geom_vline(...)` to put the vline in front of the bars.

Comment: Cheers Stefan, something as simple as that..